# Autocomplete / Typeahead possible with plain JS (without Jquery) and reading from SQLSERVER database or JSON file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, autocomplete

Currently, I have a good working autocomplete based on Jquery and reading the suggestions via an SQL select from the database. But to tune a page and getting better performance, I would like to get rid of the JQUERY overhead!

The catalogue to look into contains over 10.000 records so the rendered html would explode without using a search method via a webservice or a JSON file containing all the results.

I am not an JS expert, and the current demos work fine for bootstrap 4 (jquery?) but I haven't found a same approach for ASP.NET / JS / Bootstrap-5? or plain JS but an option to read from a JSON file or via an url from the database?!

Who can give me a kick start??

Much appreciated, Kees

I tried all the suggestions from the internet, but most autocomplete demos rely on JQUERY or I don't have found an option to use only JS but also read from a url giving me the JSON names for the select.

So this is the current Jquery version, but how can I update / make it JS compatable without JQuery:

```
jQuery(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=txtSearch.Clientid %>").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var value = { prefix: request.term };
            var testkees = JSON.stringify(value);
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("/Service.asmx/GetHostaname") %>',
                data: testkees,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('|')[0], val: item.split('|')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#<%=hfCustomerId.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
        },
        minLength: 1
    });

   });
});
```

Comment: Share what you have currently as code. We cannot fix your typeahead if you do not show it to us.